# Help with showing that the following is positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Is the following a symmetric positive definite matrix for any square matrix $A$

$$(W^{-1} A) P (W^{-1} A)^T $$

where $W, P$ are symmetric positive definite matrices.

(Maybe can show this by breaking $P = M M^T$?)

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q = (W^{-1}A)P(W^{-1}A)^T$. Now consider $x^T Q x = x^T (W^{-1}A)P(W^{-1}A)^T x$. Let $y =(W^{-1}A)^T x $. Therefore, $x^T Q x = y^T P y\ge 0$.

Also, use $(XYZ)^T = Z^T Y^T X^T$ to show that $Q$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show
$$v^\top (W^{-1} A) P (W^{-1} A)^\top v \ge 0$$
for all $v$.

You know
$$u^\top P u \ge 0$$
for all $u$.

Thus,...?